# Export password to ldap at the time of registration liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I use **liferay 6.1.2** bundled with jboss, integrated with **CAS for authentication**. Now I want to integrate **LDAP for user registration** as well. Just the registration is to be done in liferay and to be exported to LDAP and authentication using CAS. The problem I am facing is that when we register in liferay, the user gets exported to LDAP, but not his password. The password will get exported to LDAP only if we log-in using the liferay login portlet. This is actually not allowed and login should be only via CAS to LDAP. Now my idea is that the password should get saved into LDAP at the time of registration itself or any similar workarounds. I have no idea how to accomplish this. Please ask if any additional information is needed.

```
login.create.account.allow.custom.password=true
passwords.default.policy.change.required=false
ldap.auth.method=bind
```

These are the extra parameters I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an ext to accomplish this. The password is added as a modification item only when it has a change. i.e., not for the first time. I did this by extending DefaultPortalToLDAPConverter class in ext.